# Commutation of a partial trace with an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, trace

Let the partial trace $\mathrm{tr}_B$ be a mapping from an endomorphism End$\left( H_A\otimes H_B \right)$ onto an endomorphism End$\left( H_A \right)$. Then the partial trace is defined as

$$
\mathrm{tr}_B:\; S\otimes T \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(T)S
$$

with $S\in$ End$\left( H_A \right)$ and $T\in$ End$\left( H_B \right)$. Now it is stated that the partial trace commutes with (left and right) multiplication of an operator $T_A \otimes \mathrm{id}_B$ with $T_A\in$ End$\left( H_A \right)$ and $S_{AB}\in$ End$\left( H_A\otimes H_B \right)$ such that

$$
\mathrm{tr}_B\left( S_{AB} \left(T_A \otimes \mathrm{id}_B \right) \right)=\mathrm{tr}_B\left( S_{AB}  \right)T_A.
$$

Here, I am not quite sure what is happening. I would expect, that there should appear the dimension of B, so

$$
\mathrm{tr}_B\left(T_A \otimes \mathrm{id}_B\right)= \mathrm{dim}_B T_A.
$$

Intuitively, I see that the operator does only act non-trivially on End$\left( H_A \right)$ therefore the result looks reasonable. However, I am somewhat not able to express this mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S_{AB}$ can be expressed in the form
$$
S_{AB} = \sum_{k=1}^N S_A^{(k)} \otimes S_B^{(k)}
$$
for some operators $S_A^{(k)},S_B^{(k)}$ (we could be a bit more specific, but this will do). We then have
$$
\operatorname{tr}_B(S_{AB} (T_A \otimes \operatorname{id}_B)) = \\
\operatorname{tr}_B\left(\sum_{k=1}^N (S_A^{(k)} \otimes S_B^{(k)})  (T_A \otimes \operatorname{id}_B)\right) =\\
\sum_{k=1}^N\operatorname{tr}_B\left( (S_A^{(k)} \otimes S_B^{(k)})  (T_A \otimes \operatorname{id}_B)\right) = \\
\sum_{k=1}^N\operatorname{tr}_B\left( (S_A^{(k)} T_A) \otimes S_B^{(k)}  \right) = \\
\sum_{k=1}^N \operatorname{tr}(S_B^{(k)})S_A^{(k)} T_A =\\
\left(\sum_{k=1}^N \operatorname{tr}(S_B^{(k)})S_A^{(k)}\right) T_A =\\
\operatorname{tr}_B(S_{AB}) T_A
$$
as desired.